# What are the other angles in triangle?

Tags: trigonometry

What are the other angles in triangle and what is $\tan(\frac{\beta-\gamma}{2})$, if $\alpha = 60$ and $\frac{b}{c}=2+\sqrt3$?
and
I tried to solve it using law of sines and law of cosines but I couldn't find answer.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt, and exactly where you get stuck?

Comment: Also specify that a,b,c are opposite alph, beta gamma.  It's implied.  But it's not a given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$\frac{b}{c}=\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\gamma)}=2+\sqrt{3}$$
since we have $$\gamma=\frac{2}{3}\pi-\beta$$ we get
$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2}{3}\pi-\beta\right)}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}}$$
can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac{\beta-\alpha}2=x$ and we have $\beta+\alpha=120^\circ$

As $0<\beta,\alpha<\pi,-\dfrac\pi2<x<\dfrac\pi2$

$\beta=60^\circ+x,\alpha=60^\circ-x$

$$\dfrac{2+\sqrt3}1=\dfrac{\sin(60^\circ+x)}{\sin(60^\circ-x)}$$

Using [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/), $$\dfrac{\sin(60^\circ+x)+\sin(60^\circ-x)}{\sin(60^\circ+x)-\sin(60^\circ-x)}=\dfrac{2+\sqrt3+1}{2+\sqrt3-1}$$

$$\iff\tan60^\circ\cot x=\sqrt3=\tan60^\circ$$

Can you take it from here?